# yes- no code for a dimension table in postgresql version 11

Tags: postgresql, boolean

hope all is good ! I am fairly capable with postgresql 11, however, for some reason I can't get my system to accept boolean code for a project. The table name is framed, the goal is to set up a set of dimension tables for an artist friend.

Postgresql did the table code:

```
-- Table: public.Framed

-- DROP TABLE public."Framed";

CREATE TABLE public."Framed"
(
)

WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public."Framed"
    OWNER to postgres;
COMMENT ON TABLE public."Framed"
    IS 'To fill out order dimensions';
```

I copied the code from an SQL website:

```
Insert into Framed (a Framed, b text);
insert into Framed values (true, yes);
insert into Framed values (false, no);
select* from Framed;
```

Thanks in advance for the help. It is appreciated
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Your table has no columns

```
create table framed (  -- Avoid using double-quoted names
  framed boolean,
  framed_text text
);
```

Your insert syntax is not right because:

1. Unquoted `Framed` becomes `framed` and then does not match `"Framed"`
2. The column list needs to refer to columns in the table
3. None of the three lines are complete
4. The values for `yes` and `no` need to be quoted

```
insert into Framed (framed, framed_text)  -- column list here, notice no semicolon
 values     
 (true, 'yes'),
 (false, 'no');
```

Comment: Mike- Thanks for the help ! I was typing late. I did get it to work finally, which felt pretty good for my old brain.  I really do appreciate the help - Thank you very much - Dave

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using 2 columns to contain the same information. Assuming @MikeOrganek has describe your table accurately you will need constraints to ensure consistency between the 2 columns. As they stand now nothing prevents the following:

```
insert into Framed (framed, framed_text)   
 values (true, 'no') 
      , (false, 'yes');
```

Something like the following:

```
alter table framed 
        add constraint framed_bool_text_check   
            check (   (framed and framed_text in ('yes','ok','1'))      
                   or (not framed and framed_text in ('no','0'))
                  );
```

Or just eliminate the column framed_text and resurrect it on the select, or in a view, if needed.

Comment: Belayer- Thanks for being on the rope! (brother use to rock climb). Your answer is on point- it would create more data.. Back to the drawing board! Thank you for your help , I really appreciate it ! -- Dave

Comment: Interesting reference. Don't climb much anymore myself - but still enjoy what little I can. But do teach climb safety management to adults so they can take kids climbing. Hope you solve your problem. If questions come up, we'll be here.